# Auto-submitting HTML select drop-down in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I have a simple drop-down menu using HTML's select tag. The code for the select tag becomes:

```
<select name="menu_id" id="menu_id">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Dinner</option>
  <option value="2">Lunch</option>
</select>
```

In my menu.js.coffee file I have:

```
$("select#menu_id").change(-> $(this).closest("form").submit())
```

This becomes menu.js:

```
(function() {
  $("select#menu_id").change(function() {
    return $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });
}).call(this);
```

The problem is changing the select menu doesn't submit the form! It doesn't even enter the above menu.js code (I place breakpoints there and it never enters after selecting a menu option).

If I then just copy the inside of the above `(function() {`, and I paste it into the Firebug or Chrome console, then it runs as expected and changing the menu does in fact submit the form. So how am I supposed to write the coffeescript code in rails to allow forms to be submitted when a select menu is changed?

I'm using Rails 3.2.8.

Comment: Have you tried putting your code inside the `$(document).ready () ->` block?

Comment: @DaveTsunami - that was the problem! I had assumed anything in a .js.coffee file would be loaded after the page was loaded. So the code was being run, but the `select#menu_id` didn't yet exist. Put your comment into an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your code inside the `$(document).ready () ->` block.

```
$(document).ready () ->
  $("select#menu_id").change(-> $(this).closest("form").submit())
```

Answer (score 0):

document.ready functions use only when page reload occur.
you may use separate function and call using onchange.

Example:

```
    <select name="menu_id" id="menu_id" onchange="callThisFunction()">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Dinner</option>
    <option value="2">Lunch</option>
    </select>

    <form name="myform"></form>

    function callThisFunction()
    {
      document.forms["myform"].submit();
    }
```

Comment: The way you propose is not unobtrusive. Moreover, the `onchange` event that triggers `callThisFunction` is not submitting the form, its only binding a new `onchange` event. On the first run, it wouldn't only bind the new event. On the second run it would again bind another `onchange` event and submit the form. This is not the correct way.